# What is the equivalent to C++ vector<Mat> in Java?

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing

In the following code in C++ with OpenCV:

```
vector<Mat> histograms;
histograms.push_back(histogram(cell, numPatterns));
int histIdx=3;
int valIdx=1;
hist.at<int>(0,y) = histograms[histIdx].at<int>(valIdx);
```

What is equivalent to `vector<Mat>` in Java with OpenCV?

Comment: There is Java [vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) too.

Comment: I had found this link which may be helpful for someone but it does not include my scenario http://answers.opencv.org/question/11021/confusion-between-opencv4android-and-c-data-types/

Comment: I think for Mat you can use `CvMat`

Comment: Use `ArrayList`: `ArrayList<Mat> lst = new ArrayList<Mat>();
 lst.add(new Mat(...)); lst.get(index);`

Comment: I had used ArrayList as you suggest and successfully added Mats in arraylist but when I try to get Mat of specific index it gives null object exception that says I am 
 **trying to access on null object reference.**